# Как сохранить pictureBox с указанным фоном в папку?

Tags: c#

Я делаю программу на подобии Paint. У меня есть функция сохранения, но когда я сохраняю картинку, то в папке она с чёрным фоном, несмотря на то, что я указывал `pictureBox.BackColor = Color.White;`. Как мне сохранить картинку с белым фоном?

Comment: Без этого https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve бессмысленно обсуждать Вашу проблему.

Comment: Вы задаёте фоновый цвет самого пикчабокса. К фону картинки это не имеет никакого отношения.